# Request return gzip (Vietnam Characters)

Tags: unicode, decode, encode

I am scraping data from batdongsan app. I managed to find the api link and tried to use curl to get the data

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'charset:utf-8' -H 'Content-Length:182' -H 'Origin:http://batdongsan.com.vn' -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'User-Agent:Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; SM-G9500 Build/R16NW)' -H 'Host:apimap.batdongsan.com.vn' -H 'Connection:Keep-Alive' -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' -X POST 'http://apimap.batdongsan.com.vn/api/p_sync' --data-binary 'ptype=38&cate=0&city=HN&dist=0&maxarea=0&minarea=0&maxprice=0&minprice=0&ward=-1&street=-1&room=-1&direct=-1&projectid=-1&sort=0&page=3&searchType=0&client=android&m=list&pagesize=21'
```

But the decoded gzip is a brunch of character that I cannot understand. The return text is expected to be Vietnamese characters.

A sample of return:

> 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

Any thoughts?

Edit 1:
I figured out that this is base64 encoding, and I get the following byte string. But still don't know how to decode to string. Tried UTF-8

> b'\xb7"F\x16G\x16"\xa3\xb5\xb7"G\x96G\xc6V"\xa3"E\xc5W\x13VFS\xe6v\x02\x86\xc5W\x13VV3\x07\x026\xc5W\x03\x13\x033\xe6\x02\x86\xc5W\x13VF\x93\x026\x86W\xe6v\x026\xc5W\x03\x13&\x03\x026\xc5W\x13V\x16s\xe6\x02&\x1e\xe6\x02G\xc5W\x13V\x16\x13\x96\x02\x05\x16\'\xb6\x02\x84\x96\xc6\xc6\x02\xd2\x02E\x96\xd6V7\x024\x96G\x97\x02\xd2\x02\xc4\x96\xae\xe6\x02\x86\xc5W\x13V6s\x02\x87V\xd6\x02\xe6\x86\x0e\x02G\'\xc5W\x13Vf\x136\x02G\x96\xc5W\x13V&f\x07\x02\x03\x93c#C3#\x03\x83C"\xc2"\x16FF\'V77"\xa3"e\x96\xc5W\x033\x033\xe6\x86\x02EW\x97\x02\xd2\x02\x84\x16\x96\x02$

edit2:
the raw file without extraction by gzip

> `I%&/m{JJ`$ؐ@iG#)*eVe]f@{{;N'?\fdlJ!?~|?"|g]ϲ~|>Y/??}Nqsq''w_9=tYܯ&~>+_|wv6?Yg;>^f6$o~wͿ<+{YsV<{SgwNKw?
>   8wi^n8Oo?+Eu{}jg>Xd}WszR|wq8g/=w_97OO
>                            4 ;dwpR.f{uC}.Aw7/>{_'X
>                                                      7<}NZzlBx'Ovyw7$3
>                                                                       g'w.8%w=XԷ_]MUw_jO}Y|d1w>(W_~<{}%/x>qq'œ{s)8y5Xj1hh~ӻO}H?"~yG8ј
>   b_x3%^"*~"o~"ى
>                                 *}q[4~{MsL&|~AN.:ۛM[׿S+
>                                                       D2,-
>                                                           n?{{;{OBWԞљ?*|;
>   6l8+ߋtOTyxޑ>{ӫ?IwcoEI^{/V_}'*y%%SWd^<={O-me2/'^oHG⧟{*)~{H"l7;!_\ol(gиi#/
>   p}.i?Ms'i4|6]>\v7:+:{"˧WiO}=n~6յg?}ܒS>}Nή/3sz dO'>K
>   _ 'h EK}?>*w|dkgs//~OtЃ?<^wS%"}!vO^7zqIzfO矿#^%KXC~?ͼzY@G_\mm.OH?ml>{*
>                                                                                                      }Pu`ҜO?8{Fx-ȿ}$yO"~""O8=qq/^Ö<ڧ8?
>         N߹x~Jw1ߴ"uJrOGWoOx"W"_g;/ޜσF68Uu\+
>                                           oN 'K;/>M                                    Erz'IsdxX'^o,~jA<
>         D:9#4/~W7~4g;/););v>3G4ւOqE
>                                    de[{J|qܒ&}"ԯ;A!_|<"W)A|qOqF޽OO{v|߇["zFCЙt7فW2g?5'=А~ƜC>ſgÞ.V?36i׆q?M||4O
>                                                                                                            c{'ڣnqw+w/}L>TE?w?m'kx1|xk;*
>                   QWX
>                      i}p;ʡf? {5sLxEvS=_쑞#y/^b)v!dGHƆcB7'?WyZP'LhN6ޞb<f7&n>6s<>q5]<~=<cWc?-߿*9Wq=JAi`=;]`)gQ^w3:m-xo-r}SOoN>/H#9#%ڐovL|CwSEw?M9a}͇oyK[망?i(?NHFtKa_o
>   9OsLgt{cލM$[@ [Y C9ӳy \֛Wȣ{Ԯs%OtI4i/5BOYZ_%b_DuNdh.wqݐMA&IX!9|}S⸟8yUZ

Comment: suspect the data is in XML format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
› hex batdongsan | head -30
0000  b7 22 46 16 47 16 22 a3  b5 b7 22 47 96 47 c6 56  ·"F␖G␖"£µ·"G�GÆV
0010  22 a3 22 34 c5 57 13 56  16 73 e6 02 26 1e e6 02  "£"4ÅW␓V␖sæ␂&␞æ␂
0020  e6 86 0e 02 37 c5 57 13  56 46 13 02 63 02 e6 76  æ�␎␂7ÅW␓VF␓␂c␂æv
0030  1e 36 86 02 33 53 02 e6  76 5f 02 23 63 23 14 02  ␞6�␂3S␂æv_␂#c#␔␂
0040  e4 76 57 97 c5 57 13 56  36 53 e6 02 45 27 3e 96  ävW�ÅW␓V6Sæ␂E'>�
0050  c2 02 e6 86 0e 02 c5 57  03 13 13 13 c5 57 13 56  Â␂æ�␎␂ÅW␃␓␓␓ÅW␓V
0060  26 93 07 c2 02 33 02 47  c5 57 13 56 16 73 e6 76  &�␇Â␂3␂GÅW␓V␖sæv
0070  c2 02 46 96 c5 57 13 56  36 73 e6 02 47 de 36 86  Â␂F�ÅW␓V6sæ␂GÞ6�
0080  02 33 03 d6 23 c2 02 37  c5 57 13 56 46 53 02 c5  ␂3␃Ö#Â␂7ÅW␓VFS␂Å
0090  57 03 13 13 13 c5 57 13  56 36 66 c2 02 76 96 1e  W␃␓␓␓ÅW␓V6fÂ␂v�␞
00a0  02 23 e2 53 53 02 47 c5  57 13 56 66 73 22 c2 22  ␂#âSS␂GÅW␓Vfs"Â"
00b0  16 46 46 27 56 37 37 22  a3 22 45 86 16 e6 86 02  ␖FF'V77"£"E�␖æ�␂
00c0  85 57 2e e6 02 45 27 57  e6 76 02 d2 02 45 86 16  �W.æ␂E'Wæv␂Ò␂E�␖
00d0  e6 86 02 85 57 2e e6 22  c2 22 16 67 16 47 16 27  æ�␂�W.æ"Â"␖g␖G␖'
00e0  22 a3 22 86 47 47 07 37  a3 f2 f2 66 96 c6 56 43  "£"�GG␇7£òòf�ÆVC
00f0  e2 26 16 47 46 f6 e6 76  37 16 e6 e2 36 f6 d6 e2  â&␖GFöæv7␖æâ6öÖâ
0100  67 e6 f2 36 27 f6 07 f2  23 03 03 87 23 03 03 f2  gæò6'ö␇ò#␃␃�#␃␃ò
0110  23 03 13 93 f2 13 23 f2  13 13 f2 13 65 17 25 85  #␃␓�ò␓#ò␓␓ò␓e␗%�
0120  87 a7 56 f2 23 03 13 93  13 23 13 13 03 93 53 53  �§Vò#␃␓�␓#␓␓␃�SS
0130  23 93 d2 23 56 16 26 e2  a6 07 76 22 c2 22 07 27  #�Ò#V␖&â¦␇v"Â"␇'
0140  96 36 56 22 a3 22 23 e2  53 53 02 45 c5 57 13 56  �6V"£"#âSS␂EÅW␓V
0150  66 73 22 c2 22 c6 16 47  22 a3 23 03 e2 93 83 73  fs"Â"Æ␖G"£#␃â��s
0160  73 63 03 63 c2 22 c6 f6  e6 22 a3 13 03 53 e2 83  sc␃cÂ"Æöæ"£␓␃Sâ�
0170  03 03 63 33 83 43 c2 22  96 46 22 a3 23 33 83 23  ␃␃c3�CÂ"�F"£#3�#
0180  73 83 43 33 c2 22 16 27  56 16 22 a3 22 33 03 02  s�C3Â"␖'V␖"£"3␃␂
0190  d6 2b 22 c2 22 36 16 47  22 a3 22 24 1e e6 02 e6  Ö+"Â"6␖G"£"$␞æ␂æ
01a0  86 0e 02 27 96 ae e6 76  22 c2 22 46 16 47 56 22  �␎␂'�®æv"Â"F␖GV"
01b0  a3 22 13 13 f2 13 23 f2  23 03 13 93 22 c2 22 27  £"␓␓ò␓#ò#␃␓�"Â"'
01c0  f6 f6 d6 22 a3 33 d7 c2  b7 22 47 96 47 c6 56 22  ööÖ"£3×Â·"G�GÆV"
01d0  a3 22 82 03 93 43 13 e2  93 33 43 e2 03 03 93 92  £"�␃�C␓â�3Câ␃␃��
```

The content is highly repetitive, so it's not compressed, but just obfuscated. It starts with `·` 0xb7 and end with `×` 0xd7. There are 22 times of each, they pair up. This gave me the hunch that these are the curly braces in JSON, an exceedingly common format used with HTTP APIs. Looking at a character table, `{` is 0x7b and `}` is 0x7d, so the obfuscation just switches the hexdigits (nibbles) around. This gives us:

```
› hex batdongsan.nibbles_exchanged | head -30
0000  7b 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a  5b 7b 22 74 69 74 6c 65  {"data":[{"title
0010  22 3a 22 43 5c 75 31 65  61 37 6e 20 62 e1 6e 20  ":"C\u1ea7n bán 
0020  6e 68 e0 20 73 5c 75 31  65 64 31 20 36 20 6e 67  nhà s\u1ed1 6 ng
0030  e1 63 68 20 33 35 20 6e  67 f5 20 32 36 32 41 20  ách 35 ngõ 262A 
0040  4e 67 75 79 5c 75 31 65  63 35 6e 20 54 72 e3 69  Nguy\u1ec5n Trãi
0050  2c 20 6e 68 e0 20 5c 75  30 31 31 31 5c 75 31 65  , nhà \u0111\u1e
0060  62 39 70 2c 20 33 20 74  5c 75 31 65 61 37 6e 67  b9p, 3 t\u1ea7ng
0070  2c 20 64 69 5c 75 31 65  63 37 6e 20 74 ed 63 68  , di\u1ec7n tích
0080  20 33 30 6d 32 2c 20 73  5c 75 31 65 64 35 20 5c   30m2, s\u1ed5 \
0090  75 30 31 31 31 5c 75 31  65 63 66 2c 20 67 69 e1  u0111\u1ecf, giá
00a0  20 32 2e 35 35 20 74 5c  75 31 65 66 37 22 2c 22   2.55 t\u1ef7","
00b0  61 64 64 72 65 73 73 22  3a 22 54 68 61 6e 68 20  address":"Thanh 
00c0  58 75 e2 6e 20 54 72 75  6e 67 20 2d 20 54 68 61  Xuân Trung - Tha
00d0  6e 68 20 58 75 e2 6e 22  2c 22 61 76 61 74 61 72  nh Xuân","avatar
00e0  22 3a 22 68 74 74 70 73  3a 2f 2f 66 69 6c 65 34  ":"https://file4
00f0  2e 62 61 74 64 6f 6e 67  73 61 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 2e  .batdongsan.com.
0100  76 6e 2f 63 72 6f 70 2f  32 30 30 78 32 30 30 2f  vn/crop/200x200/
0110  32 30 31 39 2f 31 32 2f  31 31 2f 31 56 71 52 58  2019/12/11/1VqRX
0120  78 7a 65 2f 32 30 31 39  31 32 31 31 30 39 35 35  xze/201912110955
0130  32 39 2d 32 65 61 62 2e  6a 70 67 22 2c 22 70 72  29-2eab.jpg","pr
0140  69 63 65 22 3a 22 32 2e  35 35 20 54 5c 75 31 65  ice":"2.55 T\u1e
0150  66 37 22 2c 22 6c 61 74  22 3a 32 30 2e 39 38 37  f7","lat":20.987
0160  37 36 30 36 2c 22 6c 6f  6e 22 3a 31 30 35 2e 38  7606,"lon":105.8
0170  30 30 36 33 38 34 2c 22  69 64 22 3a 32 33 38 32  006384,"id":2382
0180  37 38 34 33 2c 22 61 72  65 61 22 3a 22 33 30 20  7843,"area":"30 
0190  6d b2 22 2c 22 63 61 74  22 3a 22 42 e1 6e 20 6e  m²","cat":"Bán n
01a0  68 e0 20 72 69 ea 6e 67  22 2c 22 64 61 74 65 22  hà riêng","date"
01b0  3a 22 31 31 2f 31 32 2f  32 30 31 39 22 2c 22 72  :"11/12/2019","r
01c0  6f 6f 6d 22 3a 33 7d 2c  7b 22 74 69 74 6c 65 22  oom":3},{"title"
01d0  3a 22 28 30 39 34 31 2e  39 33 34 2e 30 30 39 29  :"(0941.934.009)
```

This is JSON, but Latin-1 encoded.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use File::Slurper qw(read_binary write_binary);
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(JSON encode_json);
my $file = read_binary 'batdongsan';
my $nibbles_exchanged = join '', map {
    my $n = ord $_;
    my $high = $n >> 4;
    my $low = $n - ($high << 4);
    my $c = chr(($low << 4) + $high);
    $c
} split //, $file;
write_binary 'batdongsan.nibbles_exchanged', $nibbles_exchanged;
my $json = JSON->new->latin1->decode($nibbles_exchanged);
write_binary 'batdongsan.json', encode_json $json;
```

---

```
› jq . < batdongsan.json | head -30
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Cần bán nhà số 6 ngách 35 ngõ 262A Nguyễn Trãi, nhà đẹp, 3 tầng, diện tích 30m2, sổ đỏ, giá 2.55 tỷ",
      "lat": 20.9877606,
      "id": 23827843,
      "address": "Thanh Xuân Trung - Thanh Xuân",
      "date": "11/12/2019",
      "avatar": "https://file4.batdongsan.com.vn/crop/200x200/2019/12/11/1VqRXxze/20191211095529-2eab.jpg",
      "area": "30 m²",
      "room": 3,
      "price": "2.55 Tỷ",
      "cat": "Bán nhà riêng",
      "lon": 105.8006384
    },
    {
      "room": 2,
      "area": "100 m²",
      "cat": "Bán căn hộ chung cư",
      "lon": 105.767585754395,
      "price": "2 Tỷ",
      "id": 15034966,
      "title": "(0941.934.009) cắt lỗ CH Goldmark City tòa R1,2,3,4, S1,4 ở ngay, căn đẹp, tầng đẹp, cam kết giá rẻ",
      "lat": 21.0403366088867,
      "avatar": "https://file4.batdongsan.com.vn/crop/200x200/2018/03/01/20180301105228-2eb8_wm.jpg",
      "address": "Phú Diễn - Bắc Từ Liêm",
      "date": "11/12/2019"
    },
    {
      "lat": 20.9943332672119,
```

Comment: wow, that's some f'uped json - Latin 1 + Unicode escapes! Nice work.

Comment: so you directly saved the file from the curl command and do `hex batdongsan | head -30`? I tried this using xxd command but get different result.